# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm trying to create a server but it is throwing me an error in console

```
$ node server1185
Server listening at 1185

C:\Users\Bharat\Desktop\Nodejs\server1185.js:9

res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html', 'Content-Length': data.length
                                                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\Bharat\Desktop\Nodejs\server1185.js:9:
71)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13)
```

My Node.js code is following

```js
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
displayForm(res);
});

function displayForm(res){
fs.readFile('form.html', function(err,data){
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html', 'Content-Length': data.length
});
res.write(data);
res.end();
});
}
server.listen(1185);
console.log('Server listening at 1185');
```

It is throwing an error in data.length, an explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: You're not checking the `err`. Also, please don't add spam characters to your post just for padding.

Comment: `console.log(err)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the `err` object properly
Log both `err` and `data` object. You will understand the problem

```
 if(err)
    {
        console.log(err)
    }
    else
  {
   res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html', 'Content-Length': data.length
 }
```

Comment: in this case : `$ node server1185
Server listening at 1185
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Bharat\Desktop\Nodejs
\form.html'
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Bharat\\Desktop\\Nodejs\\form.html' }

`

Comment: your path to form.html is wrong. Where is that file located?

Comment: Oh yes!, form.html was in public sub-directory of Nodejs directory.

Comment: Hope it solves your problem. If yes plz mark anwer as right answer